# How to create custom MovieClip boundaries in Flash CC/Action Script 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip, flash-cc

I'm working on a small game project in Flash CC, and I've made a map for a player controlled character to move around in. The map (a MovieClip) displaces based on the direction of movement of the player (also a MovieClip). The walls encase transparent space which is filled in by the color of the scene.

I'd like to know how to create a MovieClip boundary that doesn't just surround the map in a rectangle which encases both the walls and the transparent space. Basically, I'd like a MovieClip boundary that exclusively wraps around the actual image itself. I'm unsure whether this is doable in AS3 or Flash itself.

Any work-arounds for this issue would also be appreciated if what I'm describing is unnecessary/impossible. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you're doing to create a new class, let's say Wall, that extends a Sprite ( you don't need a MovieClip for that ).

You can even create that class in Flash CC and not purely in code.

[image]

Note 3 things:

1) The wall can have a transparent fill and no outline. I chose to keep them just so you'd see it on the picture.
2) You need to tick the "Export for ActionScript" checkbox and give it a Class name ( I chose "Wall" )
3) Optionally you can change the default Base class from `MovieClip` to a `Sprite`. Won't make much difference, but it's for the better.

Then proceed placing these wall objects on the map, be it inside MovieClip or even a Bitmap - it doesn't matter. Just drag as many of the as you want from the library to the stage. You also don't need to give them instance names unless you want some specific control for a specific wall ( for example it removes itself when a player picks up a key or something )

In the game's script you can get all the walls in the beginning of the game like so:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

function getWallsInAHolder(holder:DisplayObjectContainer):Vector.<Wall>
{
    var wallArray:Vector.<Wall> = new Vector.<Wall>();

    var currentChild:DisplayObject;
    for ( var i:int = 0; i < holder.numChildren; i++ )
    {
        currentChild = holder.getChildAt( i );  
        if ( currentChild is Wall )
            wallArray.push( currentChild );
    }

    return wallArray;
}

trace(getWallsInAHolder(this).length );
```

A few important notes about the code:

1) It was written in a frame for the sake of not spending too much time.
2) You can still use the method getWallsInAHolder() in your class, it's totally self-contained.

Then it's easy to use AABB ( or any other ) collision detection to actually check if the character collides with any wall. It's even better because you don't have to program in the position ( and size ) of every each wall - just drag'n'drop them in Flash!

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give this a shot.

Comment: If the this answer is correct, please upvote and mark it as completed to help others with the same problem.

Comment: Upon looking over your answer thoroughly, I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. From what I understand, you're outlining a unique method of making many uniform walls. I've made an entire map, and I've imported it into the library, then I converted it to a MovieClip. It moves corresponding to the player, however, because MovieClip boundaries (as far as I know) can only encase things in a rectangular shape, the player just walks over everything. I'd like the player to be able to move in anything that is blank space, and stop when he hits anything that is not. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, but not from a programming point of view. If you want to process the map MovieClip to see if the given part if blank or not - it's possible, but it's a lot easier to put walls on top of a picture for several reasons: a) it's easier to process b) you might want to not check collision with every wall all the time c) having the map move has no problem with the method I described - just put the walls in the map MC and let the walls move with the map.

Comment: "That makes sense, but not from a programming point of view." That's a really good way to put it. I'm somewhat new to AS3 so I'm not entirely sure if I understand your concept, but I think that it's restricted to rectangular boundaries, right? The issue is that the map has a lot of diagonals, and it's pixelated too, so it's jagged diagonals. If we're working with rectangles, it would be incredibly inefficient for me to make walls this way. Are you able to describe the blank checking concept, despite still not being a great work-around? Thank-you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can make a circle with a class Wall too :) Or you can make a CircleWall class that has a base-class Wall. You can have lines or rotated rectangles enabled for collision detection - then you'd need to utilize ray-casting to be efficient. Pixelated/jagged lines is not an option - it takes too much CPU time to process and will not work for any decent-sized map.

Not trying to be rude, but it seems you're new to programming ( not only in Flash ), perhaps you could look for some tutorials. Flash was wildly popular some years ago - there's tons of tutorial material out there.

Comment: You're not being rude, you're correct. I am very new to programming :) Although turning the rectangles diagonally... yeah that should have been extremely obvious to me. Excuse my utter stupidity haha. I can just settle for diagonal boundaries instead of jagged diagonal boundaries, but I'm not exactly sure that I understand what your sample code is doing. Are you placing them in an array so that they you  can call them all simultaneously to move with the map graphic?

Comment: I do the following: 1) I assume the map is a Bitmap(or a movieclip) 2) put the map somewhere on stage 3) drag the rectangles ( Walls ) on top of the map image. 4) select everything (map and walls) and make that into a movieclip. 5) That new movieclip will be you final map (that you'll use in-game) 6) Get all the walls in a map [wall array] 7) Using the array check if the character is colliding with any of the walls. That's it. It should be enough to work on a small-mid size map. If you want more, you'll need to learn more about game-development.

Comment: I'll give this a shot to the best of my ability, and see how it turns out. Sorry for extending this a little too long. You've been a great help, and I really appreciate it!